# TSQL Parameterized CONTAINS

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, full-text-search

I am trying to wrestle to the ground a query that uses the Contains() method to search a full text index based on a TSQL parameter passed into the stored procedure. The Contains needs to do a prefix_search because it will be used to match partial words (such as the first 5 characters of a policy number).

This is my query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SearchMail]
(
    @AccountId int,
    @SearchTerm VARCHAR(100)
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN
        SELECT MailId, AccountId, ServerId, ToAddress, FromAddress, DateSent, DateReceived ,
                       [Subject], Body, PolicyNumber, ProducerNumber, IsRead, IsDeleted, IsImaged,
                       DateUpdated, DateDeleted, DateImaged, UpdatedBy, DeletedBy, ImagedBy  
        FROM   MailMessages
        WHERE  AccountId = @AccountId 
               AND CONTAINS(([Subject], Body, PolicyNumber, ProducerNumber, FromAddress), ' "' + @SearchTerm + '*" ')
               AND IsDeleted = 0 
               AND IsImaged = 0
    END
GO
```

But when I try to run this, the Enterprise Manager responds with an error: Incorrect Syntax near "+"

At this point, I am unsure what I may be doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SearchMail] 
( 
    @AccountId int, 
    @SearchTerm VARCHAR(100) 
) 
AS 

SET NOCOUNT ON 

BEGIN 
   Declare @SearchWithWildcard VARCHAR(200)
   SET @SearchWithWildcard = '"' + @SearchTerm + '*"' 

   SELECT MailId, AccountId, ServerId, ToAddress, FromAddress, DateSent, DateReceived, 
          [Subject], Body, PolicyNumber, ProducerNumber, IsRead, IsDeleted, IsImaged, 
          DateUpdated, DateDeleted, DateImaged, UpdatedBy, DeletedBy, ImagedBy   
   FROM   MailMessages 
   WHERE  AccountId = @AccountId  
          AND CONTAINS(([Subject], Body, PolicyNumber, ProducerNumber, FromAddress),
                       @SearchWithWildcard) 
          AND IsDeleted = 0  
          AND IsImaged = 0 
END 
GO
```

Ref [CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx):

> Specifies a match of words or phrases beginning with
>   the specified text. Enclose a prefix term in double quotation marks
>   (`""`) and add an asterisk (`*`) before the ending quotation mark, so that
>   all text starting with the simple term specified before the asterisk
>   is matched. The clause should be specified this way: `CONTAINS (column,
>   '"text**"')`. The asterisk matches zero, one, or more characters (of the
>   root word or words in the word or phrase). If the text and asterisk
>   are not delimited by double quotation marks, so the predicate reads
>   `CONTAINS (column, 'text*')`, full-text search considers the asterisk as
>   a character and searches for exact matches to `text*`. The full-text
>   engine will not find words with the asterisk (`*`) character because
>   word breakers typically ignore such characters.

Comment: I am trying to find anything that starts with the SearchTerm.  So for example, if the Search term is 'CNM000' I would want it to match 'CNM0001234' and 'CNM0003245'